# How to set up 2 separate VLAN on one switch (HP v1910-48G switch)

Tags: networking, lan

I need some advice on how to set up 2 VLAN(on one switch, I have HP v1910-48G switch) that separate broadcast domain and also share a single internet connection.

Whilst remaining separate so that the two networks cannot communicate with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure on how to create vlans on that spesific switch, but i'll give you what to look for. First off you will need to create your two diffrent vlans, assign them their own **vlan ID** and take note of them.

Then find an overview or list of your diffrent ports, you will then have to tag or untag ports depending on what kind of type that port will have.

- Tag - When putting multiple vlans in one cable, or trunking between two switches.

  Untag - What ports that will be a part of that vlan

---

Here is an example. I have one router, a switch, and 20 computers. I connect a cable to the router to the switch (backbone) on port 1. I then connect my computers on the switch from port 2-21.

Now i create the diffrent vlans, i create one that is named guestnet and one called companynet. I then **untag** the backbone (port 1) with both guestnet and companynet (if you dont want access to the internet on one of those vlans you dont untag the backbone with that vlan, then its just LAN only.)

Now i can **untag** the ports that the computers will connect to. I tag port 2-11 with guestnet and 12-21 with companynet. Theese vlans cannot communicate between them, which is great for seperating guests from the company files and servers.

Hope this helped! 
-Kad

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that one.

Can you tell me in detail about VLAN Interface for each VLAN and ip/gw of pc in VLAN.

Thank for your time :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUXpmiJpGb0 I haven't used VLAN interfaces, but i after some searching if found a video that explains what it is. If you use a configuration with a GUI look around if you find IP settings, or something similar.